# migrating images to google app engine datastore or blobstore

Tags: python, google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore, blobstore

I have property model, containing a field image_url.

```
class Property(ndb.Model):
    date_created=data.UTCDateTimeProperty(auto_now_add=True)
    # some other fields here
    image_url = ndb.StringProperty(indexed=False)
```

and image model,

```
class Image(ndb.Model):
    property = ndb.KeyProperty()
    file = ndb.KeyProperty(indexed=False)
    # some other fields
    image_url = ndb.StringProperty(indexed=False)
```

Now I have 'n' number of images for each property in my local machine. Name of each image is mapped to corresponding property id in csv file. I want to bulk upload all these images from my local machine to google app engine datastore or blobstore.
I tried to google up but feel like I am stuck, any help or reference would be highly appreciated.

Comment: Blobstore is getting deprecated in favor of Google Cloud Storage (GCS) -- use the latter, as Jaime said, **not** the former, in any new application.  And, image **data** is best kept in GCS, using the datastore only for structured **meta**data, typically info that you need to query by.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Google Cloud Storage](https://cloud.google.com/storage/) might be a better option for you:

- You get a nice program to work with it, [gsutil](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/getting-started-gsutil), that will let you upload easily from the console, so you can write your own scripts :)
- You can keep the filenames you already have, and setup your own directory structure so that it makes more sense for your app. If data is static then you might not even need support models.

Example, from the links above, on how you'd end up uploading your images:

```
gsutil cp *.jpg gs://images
```

> The cp command behaves much like the Unix cp command with the recursion (-R) option, allowing you to copy whole directories or just the contents of directories. gsutil also supports wildcards, which makes it easy for you to copy or move batches of files.

Comment: Currently I am uploading images using blobstore 
      for field_storage in self.request.POST.itervalues():
            file = File.build_by_field_storage(field_storage)
            to_put.append(file)
            image = Image.build(file=file,property=property.key)
            to_put.append(image)
            results.append(self.get_image_result(image))

Can't I have something similar, but doing it in bulk.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Also can I upload images to blobstore from console? If yes kindly you give me some snippet or reference.

Comment: Everything you need to know is in those links, and unfortunately you'll have to read up to implement this, but it's well worth your time. Still I added a snippet from the reference so you get an idea of what you'll be able to do.